# Debug + Breakpoints with Trigger.io catalyst

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, remote-debugging, trigger.io

I'm doing research on choosing a w3 framework for mobile apps(native) and came across trigger.io

As some of the team come from a very corporate / enterprisey background, Breakpoints + Debug is a key feature.  I've watched the catalyst video and it looks very cool.  However I didn't see breakpoints being set.

Do you know if its possible to set breakpoints + debug in trigger.io?  Can I remote debug javascript when my app is running on device?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger.io Catalyst is a hosted version of the Weinre open-source project. Unfortunately it does not support setting break-points.

It is possible to display log messages in the console and to query the DOM and JavaScript namespace from the console which is a big step up from alerts.

One approach to development is to build the user flow on the web first so you can use the Chrome debug tools with breakpoints. And then add the native features (which can only be tested on the device / emulator) at end. Trigger.io's [build to web](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/03/12/introducing-%E2%80%98build-to-web%E2%80%99-simple-deployment-of-your-mobile-codebase-as-a-web-app/) feature supports this mode of development:

Comment: There are experimental projects which allow for breakpoints to be added in remote debugging sessions: we've taken a look at these at Trigger and have them in our medium term roadmap.

Comment: Thanks guys.  If you don't mind sharing -- would be interested to know the experimental projects you were looking into.  Thx